# How can I get a view of tab in tablayout? not fragment's view

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I want to get a view of the second tab in the tab layout.

not Fragment's view in ViewPager.

I'm using TakuSemba's Spotlight Library.

I want spotlight to 2nd Tab.

But I can't get View of 2nd Tab in Tablayout.

How can I get a View of Tab?

EDIT :

```
 TextView tab_mypage= (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_item, null);
 tab_mypage.setText(R.string.tab_menu_mypage);
 tab_mypage.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.font_color_1));

 Drawable drawable_mypage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mypage_24);
 DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable_mypage, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.font_color_1));
 tab_mypage.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, drawable_mypage, null, null);
 tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tab_mypage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this.

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView()
```

Comment: i tried this method...but i got an nullobject error

Comment: Than set the custom view for each tab

like 

View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.text,null);

tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view);

Comment: I'm attach my code in question. getCustomView() is not working :(